# Removing View from Region in Silverlight PRISM

Tags: silverlight, prism

I have a Region which can have only one active view at a time. I want to add new view to the region on user action and remove the existing view from the same region. I also want to maintain the cache of few views. If the no of view is more than the specified limit then I will remove the oldest view. Is there any direct support for it or I have to implement the Region adapter for it. Is there any other better approach for the same?

Answer (score 2):

Well, let me answer your two questions.

First, if you want a Region to only show one view (like say you have a region defined as a ContentControl), that is possible.  You can add many views to that region and only the *active* one will be shown.  To show a different view in that region that has already been added, you would simply `Activate` that view:

```
var region = regionManager.Regions["TabRegion"];

region.Add(view1);
region.Add(view2);

region.Activate(view2);
```

In this way, you can have many instantiated views ready to go, but only one visible.

Second, with the expirations.  I'd say a region adapter would be the cleanest and most correct way, but you *could* just create an expiring cache for these and when they expire, you can remove them from the region if they aren't active:

```
var region = regionManager.Regions["TabRegion"];

region.Add(view1);
regionTracker.Add(view1, region, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
region.Add(view2);
regionTracker.Add(view2, region, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));

region.Activate(view2);
```

And then the implementation of your expiration for your regionTracker could just:

```
if(!region.ActiveViews.Contains(ViewThatJustExpired))
{
     region.Remove(ViewThatJustExpired);
}
```

It's a bit half-baked, but hopefully this will give you some idea of where to go.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my blog post about dynamic module loading in PRISM with Navigation. In that post you'll see how I use a multiple-view container, then swap views into and out of focus. It involves having an interface for navigation, then raising events that swap the view state using the visual state manager.

[Click Here to View](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2009/11/dynamic-module-loading-with-silverlight.html)

Jeremy